# I am having trouble comparing two lists. The purpose of the program is to perform offline patch installation

Tags: c#

The problem comes in the looping.  It seems to perform the comparison between the wmi qfe list and the KB list.  The issue I run into is taking and searching the contents of the .msu file name list for the KB and then installing it.  I have made a similar program in python and was mimicking a similar construct in the C# code.  Any guidance on how to make this function properly would be greatly appreciated.  The code is as follows:

```
static void Server08r2Patches()
    {
    var IE9 = from a in IAVA.Worksheet<IE9>("IE9") select a;
    var Server08r2 = from a in IAVA.Worksheet<Server08r2>("Server08r2") select a;
    var KBlist = Server08r2.Select(s=>new {KB = s.KB}).ToList();
    var ExeList = Server08r2.Select(s=>new {Executable = s.Executable}).ToList();
    string path = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)+@"\x64\");
    foreach (var item in KBlist)
    {
    if (OsPatches.Contains(item.KB))
    {
                Console.WriteLine(item.KB+" is already installed.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.KB+" will now be installed.");
                foreach (var inst in ExeList)
                {
                    do
                        {
                            var kb_inst = new ProcessStartInfo()
                            {
                                CreateNoWindow = true,
                                UseShellExecute = true,
                                FileName =path+inst.Executable,
                                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                                Arguments = (@" /quiet /norestart"),
                            };
                            try
                            {
                                Process update = new Process();
                                update.StartInfo = kb_inst;
                                update.Start();
                                update.WaitForExit();
                                Console.WriteLine(inst.Executable+" was successfully installed");
                            }
                            catch (Exception Ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message+" "+inst.Executable);
                            }
                        }
                    while (inst.Executable.Contains(item.KB) == true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what the problem is. Does it crash?

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose of the while condition (you're asking if the text contents of Executable contains the string for `item.KB`)? Also, I would have thought that ExeList would be a list of executables to install for a particular KB, however it seems to be the same for all KB's?

Comment: It goes into an infinite loop.  I initially didn't have a while loop in there and was using an if statement but the if statement would cause a null reference exception.